# Date range fields not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm a student web programmer and am having an issue with a task I was recently assigned.The previous person who held my position had created a news reporting site that is a little buggy.

The issue with the site is that when you specify a date range for which news articles to display, the dates will either revert to what they were previously or they will change to something random.  Trying to set a date before 2010 is the only way to get this issue to occur every time.  Sometimes it will work for many uses before having an issue.

Just to clarify, I'm not looking/hoping for someone to give me an outright answer/do my work for me, especially since I really am trying to learn and improve my skills. I would just really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction to solving this problem.

Here are all the references to the date from the file I'm looking over:

```
// Create dates
$year = ( isset( $get['year'] ) ) ? $get['year'] : date("Y");
$year2 = ( isset( $get['year2'] ) ) ? $get['year2'] : date("Y");
$month = ( isset( $get['month'] ) ) ? $get['month'] : date("m");
$month2 = ( isset( $get['month2'] ) ) ? $get['month2'] : date("m");
$day = ( isset( $get['day'] ) ) ? $get['day'] : date("d");
$day2 = ( isset( $get['day2'] ) ) ? $get['day2'] : date("d");

//create first and second dates for range
$t_current = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year); // Current month Unix timestamp
$t_next = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month2, $day2+1, $year2); // date2 unix timestamp for date range

// Criteria
if ( $author_url) {
    $this->EE->db -> where ( $author_name_field_id, $author_name);

$this->EE->db
    -> where ("exp_channel_titles.entry_date >= $t_current")
    -> where ("exp_channel_titles.entry_date <= $t_next");

}

else {
    $this->EE->db
    -> where ("exp_channel_titles.entry_date >= $t_current")
    -> where ("exp_channel_titles.entry_date <= $t_next");
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="datelists">
    <select id="month" name="month" style="display:none">
<?php
//lists months
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; ++$i) 
            {
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
                $value = date('m', $time);
                $label = date('F', $time);

//if month is set stay on that month    
                if($month==$value)
                    { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                    }
                else
                    {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);}
            }

  ?>
//first month selected instead of blank
        $("#target option:first")

    </select>
    <select id="day" name="day" style="display:none">   
<?php
//lists days
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) 
            {

                $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d days', $i));
                $value = date('d', $time);
                $label = date('d', $time);
//if day is set stay on that day            
                if($day==$value)
                    { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                    }
                else
                    {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);} 
            }           
//first year selected instead of blank
  ?>
    $("#target option:first")
    </select>
    <select id="year" name="year" style="display:none"> 
<?php   
//lists years
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; ++$i) 
            {                 
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
                $value = date('Y', $time);
                $label = date('Y', $time);  
//if year is set stay on that year          
                if($year==$value)
                    { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                    }
                else
                    {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);}         
            }

//first year selected instead of blank
  ?>
    $("#target option:first")
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="datepicker" />
    <select id="month2" name="month2" style="display:none">
<?php
//lists months
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; ++$i) 
            {
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
                $value = date('m', $time);
                $label = date('F', $time);
//if month is set stay on that month        
                if($month2==$value)
                    { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                    }
                else
                    {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);}
            }
  ?>
//first month selected instead of blank
        $("#target option:first")
    </select>
    <select id="day2" name="day2" style="display:none">
<?php
//lists days
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) 
            {     
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d days', $i));
                $value = date('d', $time);
                $label = date('d', $time);
//if day is set stay on that day            
                if($day2==$value)
                    { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                    }
                else
                    {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);}     
            }
//first year selected instead of blank
  ?>
    $("#target option:first")
    </select>
    <select id="year2" name="year2" style="display:none">
<?php
//lists years
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; ++$i) 
            {             
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
                $value = date('Y', $time);
                $label = date('Y', $time);  
//if year is set stay on that year          
                if($year2==$value)
                    { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                    }
                else
                    {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);}             
            }               
//first year selected instead of blank
  ?>
    $("#target option:first")
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="datepicker" />  
</div>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" value="<?php echo $month."/".$day."/".$year; ?>" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" value="<?php echo $month2."/".$day2."/".$year2; ?>" />               
<input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        </form>
               </p>
</div>     
<!--<h1><?php echo "$month/$day/$year - $month2/$day2/$year2" . ' <br/>'?></h1>-->
<?php
    if ( isset($get['institute']) && is_numeric( $get['institute'] )  ) {

        echo "<h2><center>" . $institute_cat . "</center></h2>";
    }

    if ( empty($entries) ) {
        echo "<h2><center>No articles found</center></h2>";
    }
    else {
?>
```

Javascript:

```
<!-- javascript datepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /></link>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://expeng.anr.msu.edu/css/sitewide/datepicker.css" />  </link>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#from').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                //dateText comes in as MM/DD/YY
                var datePieces = dateText.split('/');
                var month = datePieces[0];
                var day = datePieces[1];
                var year = datePieces[2];
                //define select option values for
                $('select#month').val(month);
                $('select#day').val(day);
                $('select#year').val(year);
        },                  
    }); 
    $('#to').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                //dateText comes in as MM/DD/YY
                var datePieces = dateText.split('/');
                var month2 = datePieces[0];
                var day2 = datePieces[1];
                var year2 = datePieces[2];
                //define select option values for
                $('select#month2').val(month2);
                $('select#day2').val(day2);
                $('select#year2').val(year2);
         },     
    }); 
});
</script>
```

http://msue.anr.msu.edu/news/report is the website just in case anyone was interested in seeing the problem for themselves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not good security practice to pass your $_GET variables forward without sanitizing them.  Doing so makes you vulnerable to code injection.  Take a look at EE's input class for a safer way to handle: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/input.html#Input::get

Answer (score 1):

In this section of your code (note the `for()` loop at line 47):

```
    <select id="year" name="year" style="display:none"> 
<?php   
//lists years
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; ++$i)    // Try to change this to: for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; ++$i)
            {                 
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
                $value = date('Y', $time);
                $label = date('Y', $time);  
//if year is set stay on that year          
                if($year==$value)
                    { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                    }
                else
                    {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);}         
            }
```

And this section (note the `for()` loop at line 106):

```
    <select id="year2" name="year2" style="display:none">
<?php
//lists years
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; ++$i)    // Try to change this to: for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; ++$i) 
            {             
                $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
                $value = date('Y', $time);
                $label = date('Y', $time);  
//if year is set stay on that year          
                if($year2==$value)
                    { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                    }
                else
                    {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);}             
            }               
//first year selected instead of blank
  ?>
```

It is creating a drop down selection with year from current year up to three years back. So, when you specify year beyond that (before 2010), the year is not part of the `<select>` box. Similarly for the `<select>` for `year2`.

If you want to support more years, just change the value of 3 to something else.

By the way, try to add a check for start date <= end date. I tried it, and while it doesn't give me any error, it just shows no result instead of saying it's an invalid date range.

Comment: I tried changing the value of 3 to something else but it still won't work for anything before 2010. Also, I added a check as Cwissy suggested earlier, however, I can still submit an invalid date and it will accept it like you mentioned was happening to you.

Comment: Did you change the value of 3 for both `year` and `year2`? Try to change the value to 5 and then view the page source for your generated HTML and make sure you have `<option value="2013">2013</option>` all the way to `<option value="2008">2008</option>`. I tried adding those options using firebug (in your linked page) and it worked when I submitted the page.

Comment: I'm confused, don't I just change the value of 3 in just that one for loop?  When I check the source it shows the option values going all the way to 2008 like you said, but it still automatically changes the year of any date before 2010 back to 2013 for me.

Comment: If you change the value of 3 for `year`, it will only accept 2008 for the `year` (used by `t_current`). If you change it for `year2`, it will only accept 2008 for `year2` (used by `t_next`). That's why you need to change both. Otherwise, the one which you don't change won't accept anything before 2010.

Comment: Never mind, it works if I edit the url variables directly but the javascript date picker somehow broke out of nowhere and now it won't accept anything I type in myself...

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you where the changes are needed. The date picker broke because it cannot modify the dropdown selection to the year outside its defined range. Try to disable the page's stylesheet (use web developer extension or firebug) and you can see it in action.

Comment: I disabled the page's style sheet but it still isn't working. Also, the date picker was able to go passed the original date range when it was working and I can't seem to find where it's range is being defined. I really appreciate all the help by the way!

Comment: With year up to 2008 and stylesheet disabled, it should look like [this image](http://postimg.org/image/ay5aul3mb/). When you change the value from date picker, the dropdown option will be changed. When you submit the form, it will actually submit the values in dropdown instead of values in datepicker (they're just nice skin). As such, if you don't have the years in dropdown options, there's no way the values will be sent to your PHP script to be processed.

Comment: How are you getting those dropdowns to show up? When I disable the stylesheets nothing happens to either the dev site or the actual site. Well, with the actual site an un-styled calender pops up but thats it.

Comment: Also, don't the dropdown values change after I change the values in the for loops or do I have to change them somewhere else too?

Comment: Install 'Web Developer Extension' for Firefox. There is an option to disable CSS (CSS > Disable styles > Disable all styles). Yes, the values available in the dropdown list will change once you modify the `for()` loop in your template script (see my updated answer above). When you pick a date/year in the date picker, the selection will change to whatever is available.

Comment: I see it now! How would you suggest I go about fixing the javascript issue?

Comment: To fix the javascript issue, you need to fix the HTML issue, which came from the template's PHP script. Once you fix the PHP script and have the `for()` loop (for both the year fields) support more years (eg. 5), the resulting HTML should have the `<option>`s for year 2013 to 2008. Once those are generated, the datepicker problem should be automatically "fixed". See my answer for sections that need to be changed.

Comment: Hey, so today when I tried running it it gave me no html errors and everything worked fine somehow haha. I'm a little confused as to how that happened but I wanted to thank you for all the help!

Comment: It was probably cached somehow, or maybe the source code didn't get updated. In any case, good to know it works. As a suggestion, change the supported year to go beyond 2008 to the year of first news. It will save you headache, say, in 2015 and you are searching for news from 2008.

Answer (score 0):

at this point in the code:

```
//create first and second dates for range
$t_current = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year); // Current month Unix timestamp
$t_next = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month2, $day2+1, $year2); // date2 unix timestamp for date range
```

I would definately add a check to ensure that $t_next is later than $t_current as that would be the first logic problem I would look for.

```
if($t_current>$t_next){
    // swap them over
    $tmp=$t_current;
    $t_current=$t_next;
    $t_next=$tmp;
}
```